# git: how to auto-resolve files that contains no conflicts

Tags: git, merge, conflict

We recently did some refactoring across our solution that contained a lot of refactoring, and most files were modified, some mainly namespaces. We want to merge latest dev into the feature branch, but after the merge we ended up with over a 1000 conflicts. But as we start working through the conflicts, we noticed that all the files that were merely changed due to namespaces, when opening the file up in a merge tool (Beyond Compare), it shows the changes but there are no conflicts to resolve. This indicates that the git could have automerged these files, but yet they are flagged as conflicts. I've done reading and I understand why this is, but I've tried some ways to figure out if there is a way to auto-resolve these files which contains no conflicts...

I came across this the "git merge dev -s ours" command, which uses the "ours" merge strategy.

> ours
>
> This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by
>   favoring our version. Changes from the other tree that do not conflict
>   with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary file,
>   the entire contents are taken from our side.
>
> This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which does
>   not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards
>   everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that
>   happened in it.

Now for me, this tells me that it will favour "our" changes if there are no conflicts, which is exactly what we want, because when we open the conflicted files that contains NO conflicts, all the changes in the merged file contains changes from ONLY our side.

**The problem:**

For some reason the "ours" merge stratagy auto-merged all the conflicts, selecting only "our" changes for every conflict. I would have expected it to auto-merge the files that contained no conflicts that required resolving, and kept the conflicted files that had actual conflicts for us to resolve.

Does anyone know of a better way or doing this? We are dealing with over 1500 conflicts here and it will take us a week to go through this manual process of opening the file, seeing that there is no conflicts to resolve, clicking "save", and moving onto the next. Very repetitive and time consuming.

Comment: This has never happened for me so I am a bit curious. So do the files that are flagged as conflicts (but are actually not conflicts) contains the git conflict marker `>>>` and `<<<`. If yes and if through this pattern you can recognise which file needs changing and which doesn't a bit of grep + sed may help. Correct me if my assumptions are wrong though.

Comment: My impression is that mergetools like Beyond Compare are sometimes "smarter" than git, and more aggressively resolves conflicts. E.g. ignoring whitespace changes and favoring the non-whitespace changes.

Comment: @Sohaib There are no conflict markers. When you open the file in any merge tool, in my case, Beyond Compare, it simply shows the changes, but there are no conflicts in the file, there is nothing for me to resolve, it simply wants me to click save and move to the next conflict. There are actual conflicted files which contains conflicts, but the majority of files in this given merge have no conflicts.

Comment: In which case one thing to do (not the cleanest maybe) is you just write a script that loops over all conflict files and in case they do not contain conflict markers run `git add` on them. Shouldn't take more than 15 mins of your time I guess.